# How to revoke/refresh tokens using Authlib flask client

Tags: authlib

I am using the Authlib Flask client. I'd like for a user of the client to be able to submit a request to revoke the access token, to revoke the refresh token, or to simply refresh their token.

I saw in the docs that there are methods for these, but those methods are for the HTTPX client. The method doesn't exist for the flask client - `oauth.my_client_name.revoke_token` results in `AttributeError: 'FlaskOAuth2App' object has no attribute 'revoke_token'`

How can this be done?